# Permission related to edit view on database

Tags: sql-server, permissions

What is the exact permission needed to edit a database view?

Can I give it to an active directory group account? There is no individual login.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173846.aspx#Anchor_3) for `ALTER VIEW`:

> To execute ALTER VIEW, at a minimum, ALTER permission on OBJECT is required.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I give it to an active directory group account? There is no individual login.

Yes you can. If the AD group is not a database user then add the group as database user and then you can grant it to the user. Sample script below:

```
USE DBName
GO

CREATE USER MyGroup FROM LOGIN [MyActiveDirectory\MyGroup]

--Script to grant alter for one object
GRANT ALTER ON dbo.vwGetAllData TO MyGroup

--Script to grant alter on any object to the user
GRANT ALTER TO MyGroup
```